# Show date post published in Gutenberg component

Tags: block-editor

I am coming from the PHP world where I would just put

```
<div>
  <h1><?= get_the_title() ?></h1>
  <p><?= the_time('j F  Y'); ?></p>
</div>
```

Now I have a Gutenberg `Edit.js` block.

```
<div>
    <RichText
        className="snug huge"
        placeholder="Your title here"
        onChange={(content) => setAttributes({ title: content })}
        value={attributes.title}
        tagName="h1"
    />
    <p>[The date of the page or post needs to be formatted and placed here]</p>
</div>
```

How on earth do I put the date the post was published in?

### Edit:

Recently I have found a list of all PHP template tags and their Gutenberg counterparts:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/22724

This has lead me to find the Post Date — however there is no documentation at all for it. I think it is what I am after, however I'm unsure how to use it.
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/post-date

Comment: What date? Of the post?

Comment: Yes the date of the post

Comment: is this in the edit component, or is this in the save component/what gets shown on the frontend? `RichText` components are only used int he edit component in the block editor, they shouldn't be used in the save component because they're interactive. The output of the save component is turned into static HTML that gets saved in the database. If you want something dynamic that executes PHP when it's displayed then you need to render the block using PHP, which means that your first and original code is the solution

Comment: @TomJNowell It is in the Edit component. I am trying to make the editing experience look as similar as possible to the viewing experience, so I would like to show the post date within the Gutenberg editor. This means I can't use PHP — if you ignore my first code snippet, I purely want to show the date of the post in the Gutenberg editor.

Comment: Nice find with the post-date block! What is the problem with using [their method described here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/post-date/edit.js#L37-L76)?

Comment: could this not be a block pattern with a title block that has the `snug huge` classnames predfined in its attribute? I don't see why a custom block is necessary

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell I'm not interested in the title. I am interested in the date of the post. I don't know how to show the date of the post in the Gutenberg editor as I mention in the title, content and code of this post. How can I show the date the post was published in the Gutenberg editor?

Comment: I was just suggesting that you can bypass the problem entirely with a block pattern containing a group block, post title block, and post date block. Note that these are not answers to your specific question, just comments that might solve your problem. Answers are posted below in larger text with voting controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get there by doing the following.

```
import * as wpDate from "@wordpress/date";
```

You can find the very limited documentation on that here: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-date/

I was able to use the following:

```
const post = wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPost();
const postDate = wpDate.format("d|m|Y", post.date);
```

Then, when I needed it:

```
<div>
    <RichText
        className="snug huge"
        placeholder="Your title here"
        onChange={(content) => setAttributes({ title: content })}
        value={attributes.title}
        tagName="h1"
    />
    <p>{postDate}</p>
</div>
```